# Unexpected unknown type selector In Sonarqube using Ionic 3

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, sonarqube

[image: 1]

I am facing this " unknown type selector" In ionic 3  while evaluating my code in Sonarqube how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please elaborate a little more. The description of your problem is a little bit short.

Comment: Need more details

Comment: @JanithaRasanga ok Actually while I am testing my front end code in sonarQube I am facing a one bug issue which is of critical category in which it is saying that the selector name that is provided in CSS file is not correct I am using Ionic 3 as a frontend framework although I had searched a lot no such specific pattern is provided to define selector name as per sonarQubes Rules.